# c++ dynamic allocation initial values

Tags: c++, string, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, strcat

I'm trying to concatenate two strings into a new one (finalString) like this:
finalString = string1 + '&' + string2

Firstly, I allocate the memory for finalString, then i use strcat().

```
finalString = new char[strlen(string1 ) + strlen(string2) + 2];

cout << finalString  << endl;

finalString = strcat(finalString , string1 );
finalString = strcat(finalString , "&");
finalString = strcat(finalString , string2);

cout << finalString  << endl;
```

I'll suppose that string1 is "Mixt" and string2 is "Supermarket".

The output looks like this:

```
═════════════════řřřř     //(which has 21 characters)
═════════════════řřřřMixt&Supermarket
```

I know that if I use round brackets in "new char" the string will be initialized to 0 and I'll get the desired result, but my question is why does the first output has 21 characters, supposing that I allocated only 17. And even so, why does the final string length exceed the initial allocation size (21 > 17) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason why you can't use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: `finalString` starts out uninitialized, so this is undefined behaviour. You should set the first element to 0 (e.g. `finalString[0] = 0;`)

Comment: You're wrong when you say "the string will be initialized to 0".

Comment: @Insilico, I'm using: "using namespace std"

Comment: @IoanFulgeanu if you are `using namespace std` then you should definitely use `std::string` it will be written like `string` but you will be using the `stl` type `string`. This would absolutely be a better way to do this code. If you need a `char *` then at the end you can even do `mystring.c_str()`.

Comment: @Ioan Fulgeanu: How would a `using namespace std` prevent you from using a `std::string`, which would make string concatenation trivial?

Comment: @Insilico If people started doing sensible stuff, like using `std::string` where they should be, you and I would most likely still be sitting at <10K rep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two words for you "buffer overrun"

The reason you have 21 characters initially is because there is a '/0' (also called null) character 22 characters away from the memory address that finalString points to. This may or may not be consistent based on what is in your memory.

As for the reason why you have a longer than what you wanted again you wrote outside the initial buffer into random memory. You did not crash because you did not write over something important.

strcat will take the memory address given, find the first '/0' it finds and from that place on it will copy the data from the second memory pointer you provide until the first '/0' it finds there.

What you are doing is VERY DANGEROUS, if you do not hit a /0' before you hit something vital you will cause a crash or at minimum bad behavior.

Undersand in C/C++ a char[] is just a pointer to the initial memory location of the first element. THERE ARE NO SAFEGUARDS! You alone must be careful with that..

if you set the first character of the finalString[0] = 0 then you the logic will work better.

Answer (score 0):

As a different answer, why not use `std::string`:

```
std::string a, b, c;
a = "part1";
b = "part2";
c = a + " & " + b;
std::cout << c << '\n';
```

---

```
part1 & part2
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/pjqz9T

It will make your life easier! You should always look to use stl types with `c++`.

If you really do need a `char *` then at the end you can do `c.c_str()`.

Comment: That's not my question. I'm wondering why the first cout prints 21 characters and not 17, as only 17 are allocated.

Comment: @IoanFulgeanu thats fine, this is a different and easier way to do what you want, if you need to use `char arrays` then I am sure you have a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not initialized which leads to undefined behavior. In `strcat`,  string will be appended when it finds the null character.

So, as others already mentioned, either you can do 
`finalString[0] = 0;`

or in place of your first `strcat` use `strcpy`. This will copy the first string and put a null character at the end.

> why 21 characters?

This is due to undefined behavior. It will keep on printing until it won't find a null or else it will crash as soon as it tries to access any illegal memory.